# Android Push notification- Only show the notification message to user

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, push-notification, sapui5

I am trying to include Push Notification in my Hybrid Application.
While doing this, I am able to send the push notification message from rest client and also able to receive the notification in my Android device.
Now I want to the device user to get only the alert message which I send from the server.

For example:
In the body of my Post method,I am sending:

**{ 
       "alert": "Hello android"
}**

Then, only "Hello Android" should be visible to him, even if I open the application.

Currently,when I test the above example,
when the user's app is open, he gets an alert message with details related to gcm sender, collapse_key information, apart from the alert message.

I am attaching screenshot here
[image][image]

```js
function processNotification(notification) {
 console.log("Hi! You have received a notification: " + JSON.stringify(notification));
 alert("Hi! You have received a notification: " + JSON.parse(notification));
 if(sap.Push.isPlatformIOS()){
         sap.Push.resetBadge(resetBadgeSuccess);
 }
}
```

Any Help would be appreciated

Comment: Could you provide more information - which hybrid technology are you using? Is it cordova, react-native, nativescript, etc. Also it looks like you are using a specific SDK/platform. Please also include this.

Comment: Hi @VasilDininski, It is Cordova based.

Comment: and what is this `sap.Push.isPlatformIOS()` - is that from a plugin or some platform's SDK? Are you communicating directly with GCM an intermediary?

Comment: Hi @VasilDininski ,

if(sap.Push.isPlatformIOS()){
         sap.Push.resetBadge(resetBadgeSuccess);
 }
This is  not important as my Platform is Android,
We are actually using SAP HCPMS to define the backend and Push details like API key and GCM sender
Hope this helps 
Br
Suraj

Comment: In order to fix the issue you are having you should replace the line `alert("Hi! You have received a notification: " + JSON.parse(notification));` with `alert(notification.payload.alert);`. That should do it. In general when posting again on SO please include some more details - for example that you are using SAP platform and making a cordova-based mobile app

Comment: Ok..Sure.
I will try this and come back to you.
Thanks :)